# How to find the spot of NSInvalidArgumentException of NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Xcode is throwing exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM
>   insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

However in debug mode it does not halt where the exception happened. It ends in

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

with message "SIGABRT". Stack trace only shows this "main".

Is there any way to figure out where in the code a nil object has been attempted to get inserted in an array?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Answer (score 27):

In your project, go to the Breakpoint navigator, click the **[+]** button and **Add Exception Breakpoint...**. Click **Exception > All**, and **Break > On Throw**, click **[Done]**.

With this setting in place, Xcode should break at the place in your project where the exception is thrown. You may need to walk down the stack for a frame or two to get to your code.