# Swift App crashes after 2 seconds of running Firebase

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, mobile

I recently changed my Macbook to a newer one (it's an M1 if that helps) and commuted my iOS app of mainly SwiftUI and Firebase, to GitHub, except for cocoapods, which I installed later in my computer to get the Firebase services.

The problem is that after running my app, the simulator crashes after 2 - 5 seconds, and prints the following error:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FBLPromise HTTPBody]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000021be3a0'`

I would add more code to the post but I don't know what's causing it.

Comment: Is it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70959972/fblpromise-httpbody-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71731600/fblpromise-httpbody-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-0x600001afa700-er

Comment: Some times I faced this issue. And, when I check Activity Monitor, there were two app instance on there. After closed all instance of my apps and run my project, issue was fixed.

Comment: Insert a symbolic breakpoint for `NSInvalidArgumentException`. For instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14045618/9086770

Comment: Done. Breakpoint jumps in line 330 of ``GDTCCTUploadOperation`` in ``if (response.HTTPBody) {...}`` and says: ``Thread 7: "-[FBLPromise HTTPBody]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600002e46d00"``

Comment: Did someone find the solution to this issue? @MattleeCode